# Two identical generated databases with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, integration-testing

I have build an application with Entity Framework 6, created some methods to insert an extract data from a database, and I would now like to test it for both a production- and a debugging environment.

To be sure it all works as I would like it to, the debugging database should erase all data for my tests, while my production should keep its data.

I have two projects: `MyApp.Database` and `MyApp.Database.Test`, and they each have a connection-string in their `app.config`-file, which the program loads as so:

```
public DatabaseContext() : base("name=MyDB")
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>()); 
}
```

and connection-string, where the `database` parameter set to `MyProdDB` and `MyTestDB`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Host=localhost;user id=myUser;password=myPassword;database=MyProdDB" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I run the application, and run the tests, I get the correct connection-string for each type of database.
But I get an error when I run my **tests**:
`42P01: relation "dbo.Tags" does not exist`. A simple message, saying I have not migrated my data into my test database.

But how do I migrate it into the test database?

I tried selecting the test-project in the `Package manager Console`, and running the following commands:

```
PM> Add-Migration "Init"
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'MyApp.Database.Test'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'MyApp.Database.Test'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

PM> Enable-Migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'MyApp.Database.Test'.
```

Do I need to specify my own `DbContext` class for `MyApp.Database.Test` which is almost a replica of `MyApp.Database`?

Comment: I'm confused as to whether you are trying to configure unit tests or two different environments - PROD and DEV. IAC, you probably only want your context in a single project which is where migrations will live. To update PROD you can either switch your connection string (in the context project) to point to PROD and run the migrations, or you can generate a script to update the other database "update-database -Script".

Comment: I need integration tests for the same environment. I don't want to loose data in PROD - only in DEV. My PROD is up-to-date, and works as it should. If I try to run ``Update-Database -Script`` it says I have no pending explicit migrations. Can I ask it to take every migration from 0?

Comment: Turns out I can: ``Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0``. Lets see where that takes me...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need data in your DEV environment, just drop database. You use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, so it will create new database with up-to-date schema.
More then it, you can configure your initializer in config file. Use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists inializer on PROD and DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges on DEV. So if model will change, you will have to use migrations on PROD, but DEV will just drop database and create again.

Example:

```
<contexts>      
  <context type="Elmah.SqlServer.EFInitializer.ElmahContext, Elmah.SqlServer.EFInitializer">
    <databaseInitializer type="Elmah.SqlServer.EFInitializer.ElmahDatabaseInitializer, Elmah.SqlServer.EFInitializer" />
  </context>      
</contexts>
```

or look [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: That is part of the solution, I believe - but DEV still does not contain any tables... Don't I need to do some sort of ``Update-Database`` on it?

Comment: after executing CreateDatabaseIfNotExists inializer database will contain all tables of schema, that described in your Model

Comment: That means I do the following in the same file: https://gist.github.com/Limro/48017ebbd7e80f95e76396a7f7231f02

Comment: Yes. If u set System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>()); and call it, it will drop database and create new one. don't forget to remove System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>()); from Model constructor. Remember, that model initializer will not execute unitl u access Model's entities by Model.Entities.ToArray() or by Model.Database.Initialize(true);

Comment: This gives me an exception: ``ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.`` in my ``ProductionConfig``'s only line.

Comment: it is not about "Two identical generated databases with Entity Framework 6", it's an another issue